# Excel VBA changing the text within the textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the number in my text box.

My code so far looks like this:

```
 Sub Box()
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Asbuilt_Number1").Copy
 ActiveSheet.Range("C25").PasteSpecial
 Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.textRange.Characters.text = "2"
 Selection.Name = "Asbuilt_Number"
 End Sub
```

what is based from the Macro

```
 Sub Boxes_Two()
 '
 ' Macro3 Macro
 '

 '
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Asbuilt_Number_1")).Select
 Selection.Copy
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft -0.75
 Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 347.25
 Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.textRange.Characters.text = "2"
 With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.textRange.Characters(1, 1). _
    ParagraphFormat
    .FirstLineIndent = 0
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.textRange.Characters(1, 1).Font
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .Size = 15
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Asbuilt_Number_1")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "Asbuilt_Number"
Selection.Name = "Asbuilt_Number"
 End Sub
```

I am unhappy with macro, since my copied number goes in completely different place, than I targeted.

My non-macro code throws error: Object doesn't support this property or method
at the line

```
     Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.textRange.Characters.text = "2"
```

Even if I remove the `Characters`, likewise in the template below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.shaperange.textframe2

[image]

How can I change the name of my textboxes swiftly?

Comment: Don't you work in Excel? Is your shape "Asbuilt_Number1" a sheet text box?

Comment: Yes, this is my Textbox ID

Comment: Then try this short and correct way: `ActiveSheet.Range("C25").value = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Asbuilt_Number1").OLEFormat.Object.Object.text`.  This should replace all the code of your `Sub Box()`.  In this way you can copy the text box value in that specific cell. What do you want to copy, in fact? Only part of the text? Can you explain that (IN WORDS)?

Comment: I am getting still the same error, that VBA doesn't support this method :(

Comment: So, do you have such a text box named "Asbuilt_Number1" on your active sheet? If yes, does it have any text load? If not, what "Asbuilt_Number1" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, let's try the following code:

Note: `ActiveSheet.Range("C25").Paste` will not work

```
Sub Box()
 With ActiveSheet
    .Shapes("Asbuilt_Number1").Copy
    [C25].Activate
    .Paste
    .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Name = "Asbuilt_Number2"
    .Shapes("Asbuilt_Number2").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "2"
 End With
End Sub
```