# Get location of selected charcters inside textframe if an Excel object with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Is there a programmatic way (with VBA) to get the beginning and end positions of selected text inside a TextFrame object (of a text box) on an Excel spreadsheet? Like here below for "problem".
[image]

I was looking for something in Characters method but did not find anything.

Comment: This Textframe is also called a Shape in Excel. As far as I know this shape object should have an textframe2 property you can work with. [SomeCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60605537/excel-vba-changing-the-text-within-the-textbox) See the Link for some code to get an idea.

Comment: I can get all the way to Characters, even in a specific range by using:
ActiveSheet.Shapes("tbArticle").TextFrame.Characters(10, 10)
I see more properties going down but there is nothing about "selected" state.

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain what the end goal is, we could suggest something else?

Comment: The goal is to assign an annotation to a span in text by reading location of the span from selection.

Comment: It does not have to be done in a textbox. It could be done in userform or even just regular cell. I need some object with text where specific phrases can be selected, then I would initiate VBA code (by hotkeys, icons or context menu), then some (other) userform would pop-up, where an annotation is selected, then the annotation must be saved by VBA somewhere in the spreadsheet with the beginning and end of the text span.

Comment: I was able to get it done by using a textbox on a userform. However, I cannot special format for specific spans of text with userform's textboxes.

Private Sub bAdd_Click()

    r = ActiveCell.Row

    For c = 4 To 33

        If Cells(r, c).Value = "" Then

            b = fArticle.TextBox1.SelStart

            l = fArticle.TextBox1.SelLength

            Cells(r, c).Value = Me.cbTerm & " [" & b & ";" & l & "]"

            ActiveCell.Characters(b, l).Font.Color = vbGreen

            Exit For

        End If

    Next c

    Me.Hide

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reach into the selection in a regular textbox.  If you can use an ActiveX textbox, then this is possible. You can insert an ActiveX text box from the Developer tab of the ribbon as seen here:

[image]

This will make a text box name textbox1 as seen here:

[image]

Here's a subprocedure accessing the selected text:

```
Sub selected_text()

    Dim tb As Object
    Set tb = ActiveSheet.TextBox1
    Debug.Print Mid(tb.Text, tb.SelStart, tb.SelLength)

End Sub
```

On note is that get an "enter" character in the text box, users need to use "ctrl+enter"

Comment: I am not sure it will work. Is there a way to select a span of text without entering Design Mode by clicking a spacial control on a ribbon? So far I have been having troubles with an ActiveX text box all together. It lags, does not react...

Comment: Yes, once you are out of design mode, you should be able click on it and select text very similar to a regular textbox

Comment: Did this do the trick?  If so, you should accept the answer.  If not, tell us what you experience so we can see if we can find another way.

Comment: I decided not to deal with ActiveX controls. I could not figure out how they work at all. I also suspect they will not stable under different installations of Excel. So I went a different route.